# How to play videos with phone's standard video player app

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I want to play videos i have stored in the external storage with the phone's standard video Player app. I've tried using FileProvider, but I can't manage to pass the video to the player.

```
private void passVideo(String videoname){
        File videoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video_folder");
        File newFile = new File(videoPath, videoname);
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.provider", newFile);
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setType(getContentResolver().getType(path))
                .setStream(path)
                .getIntent();
        shareIntent.setData(path);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Open Video..."));
    }
```

With this code I manage to get the Chooser for gmail, whatsapp and other social media platforms, but that's not what I want and they all say they can't handle the file format anyway. It also gives the option to play the video with VLC, but it instantly crashes.
I have tried every possible file format and none of them works.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` is for `ACTION_SEND`, which is not the typical `Intent` action for playing a video. `ACTION_VIEW` would be more typical. So, try:

```
private void passVideo(String videoname){
    File videoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video_folder");
    File newFile = new File(videoPath, videoname);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.provider", newFile);
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    viewIntent.setType(getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(viewIntent);
}
```

Comment: This worked for getting video player apps in the chooser, thank you very much. But it still says that the video can't be played and VLC just stays black

Comment: @J.P: That may be a bug/limitation with VLC's handling of this sort of `Uri`. Either that, or the video itself is corrupt.

Comment: I've tried multiple videos and formats and none of them seems to work in any app

Comment: @J.P: Try changing `viewIntent.setType(getContentResolver().getType(uri));` to `viewIntent.setType("video/mp4");`, substituting in the actual MIME type for your content. Or, log the value returned by `getContentResolver().getType(uri)` and see if it looks correct. I don't usually use `getContentResolver().getType()` for my own content, since I already know what MIME type it is.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work, I've also tried passing a pdf instead of a video and it didn't work either

Comment: @J.P: FWIW, [here is a Java sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8) demonstrating the use of `FileProvider` for `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get the chooser with the above code. The video does not play on the Media Player but plays on Chrome. Is there a way to hardcode to play on chrome?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana: Not every Android device has Chrome and not every one of your users will want to use Chrome.